# YouTube API - Manipulating URL to get Monthly Views (No OAuth 2.0)

Tags: php, oauth, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to write a little PHP script to grab the monthly views of a YouTube channel, (like how SocialBlade does it) I've been trying to get the monthly views of the user Pewdiepie as an example and am having trouble getting the data by manipulating the URL.

I would be able to get the data using OAuth 2.0 if the user logged in but i'm not planning to use OAuth in my script.

Here's the URL i'm using to try and grab the channel's data:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&start-date=2014-08-01&end-date=2014-09-01&forUsername=pewdiepie&key={my-api-key}

The: **&start-date=2014-08-01&end-date=2014-09-01** doesn't seem to place any affect on the outcome?
Could somebody explain why and how i can work-around this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the code that you're stuck with?

Comment: It wasn't code. It was simply the URL parameters not showing correctly therefore me being unable to retrieve the data via JSON_DECODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mixed a couple of different endpoints together. The start-date and end-date parameters are for the YouTube Analytics API, not the Data API ... through the Data API, you can only retrieve the current state of some of these basic channel stats (a good way to look at it is that the data API will provide you with the info you might glean by visiting the YouTube.com site ... current subscribers, view count, video count, etc.). And as the Analytics API requires oAuth2 authorization for all requests, you wouldn't be able to do what you're hoping right away. Your only option (and, my guess, how SocialBlade does it) would be to track users on a regular basis and maintain your own historical data.

Comment: Thank you, you just backed up my theory on how Socialblade does this by indexing channels on a regular basis. I will take a look into the analytics API! Thanks!